# Binding a Command inside a Style

Tags: wpf, binding, mvvm, command

I'm currently working on a WPF application that uses MVVM.  I've got a ListBox with a style set up to make it display like a RadioButtonList as follows:

```
<Style x:Key="RadioButtonList" TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{x:Null}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" >
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2" />
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                            <Border Background="Transparent">
                                <RadioButton Focusable="False" IsHitTestVisible="False" IsChecked="{TemplateBinding IsSelected}" Content="{Binding Path=DisplayName}" Command="{Binding ElementName=ShippingWindow, Path=DataContext.ShipOtherMethodSelected}">
                                </RadioButton>
                            </Border>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<ListBox Name="lbShipOtherMethodOptions" Style="{StaticResource RadioButtonList}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ShipOtherMethodOptions}" Margin="13,74,366,282" />
```

What I'm trying to do is bind a command to the RadioButton, so that I can fire off an event when a selection is made.  I've got the following code in my viewmodel, but I can't seem to get it to fire:

```
    private ICommand shipOtherMethodSelected;
    public ICommand ShipOtherMethodSelected
    {
        get
        {
            return shipOtherMethodSelected ??
                   (shipOtherMethodSelected = new RelayCommand(param => ShipOpenItems(), param => true));
        }
    }

    private void ShipOpenItems()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("GOT HERE");
    }
```

I'm pretty new to WPF and MVVM, so I'm probably missing something obvious.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

**EDIT:**
Per jberger's suggestion, I put in some code that I attempted that didn't work.  Setting breakpoints in that section didn't get tripped, nor did the message box show up.

**EDIT 2:** 
So after inspecting the DataContext on the sender, it turns out it was pointing to the object that I'm binding the RadioButton to, and not my viewmodel.  I updated the code above (adding in an x:Name to my window and updating the Command binding), and now I'm getting the event to fire when its initially bound, but it doesn't fire when I select a value.  Seems like we're getting really close now.

Comment: you didn't bind `ShipOtherMethodSelected` in your xaml

Comment: sorry, I tried that, but I must've reverted before copy/pasting my code.  I'll fix that up

Comment: what happens if you remove `Focusable="False" IsHitTestVisible="False"`? if you hook into the `Click` event, does it fire when clicked?

Comment: Removing the Focusable and IsHitTestVisible didn't give me any change in results.  Hooking into the Click event did fire however.  Seems odd that I can't seem to get it to bind to my ICommand though.

Comment: in the `Click` event handler use the debugger to browse the `sender`, and check the `DataContext` to ensure it contains `ShipOtherMethodSelected`

Comment: How are you setting your DataContext?

Comment: Interesting, the datacontext is showing as the object that the radiobutton is being bound to, and not my ViewModel.  I'll post another edit.

Comment: now what happens if you remove `Focusable="False" IsHitTestVisible="False"`? (i'd keep them removed until the end..)

Comment: You know, I think that finally did it.  I got the message box to pop up after selecting an item.  Could you type up a quick summary as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ShipOtherMethodSelected` is in your (main) `ShippingVM` NOT your `ShipItemVM`, so you need to set

```
Command="{Binding ElementName=ShippingWindow, Path=DataContext.ShipOtherMethodSelected}"
```

where `ShippingWindow` is the `x:Name` of an element "above" the `ListBoxItem`

Also, the `Focusable="False" IsHitTestVisible="False"` is denying the click.  Remove the setters.